# In ASP.NET MVC, how to generate repeated name ('?v=1&v=2&v=3') query strings with Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is NOT a question about how to correctly bind a series of check boxes to a model property (a common question) - my site works perfectly reading checkbox values from a request, either POST or GET + query string.

This is about how to use `Html.ActionLink` to generate a link that formats multiple checkbox values correctly in the query string.

So I have the following model:

```
public class ModelType
{
    public string[] V { get; set; }
}
```

And I bind, say, 3 checkboxes to that model in the view as I have three possible values (and, yes, combinations of said values).

Here is the final Html

```
<INPUT id="chk1" value="1" type="checkbox" name="V">
<INPUT id="chk2" value="2" type="checkbox" name="V">
<INPUT id="chk3" value="3" type="checkbox" name="V">
```

If all three values are checked when the form is submitted to the server as a GET then the generated query string is, of course, `?V=1&V=2&V=3`.

Model binding works beautifully, and everything is happy.

However, let's say I want to *produce* a link to the same action, passing either an anonymous type or `RouteValueDictionary` to produce the same query string; logic states that you would do something like this:

Version 1: With an instance of `ModelType` as the model on the view:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Test link", null /* action name */, new { V = Model.V }) %>
```

Version 2: Initialising the 'V' member directly as an array:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Test link", null /* action name */,
    new { V = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" } }) %>
```

*[In the question I say `RouteValueDictionary` because in both cases both of these anonymous types are getting turned into such before link generation occurs.]*

In both cases the query string that is produced is as follows: `?V=System.String%5B%5D`.

Now, I understand that this is because the link generator is simply calling `ToString()` on the array; but it would seem that there is no way to pass MVC a value that will cause it to generate `?V=1&V=2&V=3`.

Since neither the language lets us do:

```
new { V="1", V="2", ... }
```

Nor RouteValueDictionary lets us do:

```
d["V"] = "1"; d["V"] = "2"; ...
```

I've also tried the desperate measure of pre-processing a RouteValueDictionary, so that for each `IEnumerable<string>`, I produce a single string with each value separated by a comma, and then write that string back - so the query string ends up like this: `?V=1%2C2%2C3`.

But of course MVC doesn't automatically bind such a string to an array (you just get one string in the array with the commas in it); so each property that will be bound in this way has to be custom bound - which, for me, just seems like a few too many hoops to be jumping through.

So it seems that I'm stuck.

Am I missing something? Will I need to write special versions of ActionLink that do what I want?

Any help, as always, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've gone and researched this and this is my view.  I hope somebody can come up with a more optimistic answer, but somehow I think not.

Following the `Html.ActionLink` extension method all the way through, the core URL that it produces is generated by the (cough)*sealed* and (cough cough!)***internal*** class `System.Web.Mvc.ParsedRoute` and it's method `Bind` in the `System.Web.Routing` assembly.

At the very end of this method (this is a Reflector listing) - this is how it generates the query string:

```
if (unusedNewValues.Count > 0)
{
    bool flag5 = true;
    foreach (string str2 in unusedNewValues)
    {
        object obj5;
        if (acceptedValues.TryGetValue(str2, out obj5))
        {
            builder.Append(flag5 ? '?' : '&');
            flag5 = false;
            builder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(str2));
            builder.Append('=');
            builder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(
              Convert.ToString(obj5, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        }
    }
}
```

I should mention first that `unusedNewValues` is a `HashSet<string>` which means - unfortunately - that it will only ever render ***one name/value*** pairing.

You can't fudge the data string with embedded `a=b&a=c(...)` strings because the string value is escaped - thus it is not possible to generate such query strings in Mvc at all unless you replace the routing framework.

As a result, an alternative will be to write a collection data type which does something like the following (this is a dirty implementation):

```
public class StringCollection : List<string>
{
  public override string ToString()
  {
    //use the pipe character as a delimiter - but this doesn't work
    //if the strings being carried around ccould naturally contain '|'!
    return string.Join("|", this.ToArray());
  }
}
```

And then implement a custom model binder (deriving from `DefaultModelBinder`) for the type that first uses the default method and then checks to see if the resulting collection only has one string which has '|' characters in it.  If so, it then post-processes the collection, replacing its contents with the expanded values from the single string.

This is horrid - but the least nasty of all the solutions I can currently think of.

Just now have to make a load of changes to all my existing model types that use collections of strings that might be bound to query string values...

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem recently. I ended up ditching the HtmlHelper/RouteValueDictionary and just constructed my URL from scratch. Something like:

```
<a href="/Controller/Action?<%: string.Join("&", set.Select(i => "v=" + i))%>">Link</a>
```

May not appeal to everyone's tastes, but it worked for me.